# Creating a simple timer application

Tags: c, windows, linux

gcc 4.4.3
vc++ 2008

I would like to make a timer application would be portable on windows and linux. However, would be suffice to start with.

My idea is to start a timer and set it for a specified number of seconds. When the time expires call a callback function.

Is that the best way to do this?

Many thanks,

Comment: What you describe does not sound like an "application"; it sounds like a tiny part of a programming interface (API). Also, your question text is weirdly incomplete, the second sentence just stops. I suggest editing it.

Comment: can't you use existing library which does that ? "boost::asio::deadline_timer" is the one you are looking for.

Comment: take a look at this example, http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_43_0/doc/html/boost_asio/example/timers/tick_count_timer.cpp

Comment: use a library that provides this for you hiding the differences between operating systems

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do a timer. It is not hard but you need to think exactly what you want. If you want to call a callback, you usually use a thread that sleep until your delay is elapsed, before calling your callback. If you don't want to use a thread, you can call periodically a checker function that compute the time delta.

You api will be a function taking the delay and a function pointer plus the callback parameters. It will launch a thread that will sleep for the delay, then call the callback with the given parameters.

Check general purpose libraries, they usually have timers implemented (gtk+ glib, boost::timer I think).

my2c

Edit:

For the portability part, you have of course to write two versions of your timer function. If you use thread that means it is better to use a lib. As libs give you timers ... Use a lib :)

Answer (score 1):

Windows and linux do timers differently.  I suggest that you encapsulate the timing functionality into a class.  You'll have to write the class twice (once for each platform) but then the rest of the program can be the same.

Alternatively you can use a toolkit where somebody else gas already done it for you. e.g. QT or Boost.

Answer (score 0):

I have worked with several such timers in both C and C++. For C GTK example on the following url may be helpful http://zetcode.com/tutorials/gtktutorial/gtkevents/. In C++ I used glib timer https://developer.gnome.org/glibmm/2.34/classGlib_1_1SignalTimeout.html (although it is not precise). I also work with libev (which uses epoll() on Linux and select() on Windows) for better precision timer. For C, I present an example below

```
//This program is demo for using pthreads with libev.
//Try using Timeout values as large as 1.0 and as small as 0.000001
//and notice the difference in the output

//(c) 2013 enthusiasticgeek for stack overflow
//Free to distribute and improve the code. Leave credits intact
//On Ubuntu (assuming libev is installed) compile with the command - gcc -g test.c -o test -lev

#include <ev.h>
#include <stdio.h> // for printf
#include <stdlib.h>

double timeout = 1.0; //seconds
ev_timer timeout_watcher;
int timeout_count = 0;

static void timeout_cb (EV_P_ ev_timer *w, int revents) // Timer callback function
{   
    ++timeout_count;
    printf("%d\n", timeout_count);
    w->repeat = timeout;
    ev_timer_again(loop, &timeout_watcher); //Start the timer again.
}

int main (int argc, char** argv)
{
    struct ev_loop *loop = EV_DEFAULT;  //or ev_default_loop (0);
    ev_timer_init (&timeout_watcher, timeout_cb, timeout, 0.); // Non repeating timer. The timer starts repeating in the timeout callback function
    ev_timer_start (loop, &timeout_watcher);

    // now wait for events to arrive
    ev_loop(loop, 0);

    return 0;
}
```

For more docs on libev view http://doc.dvgu.ru/devel/ev.html